# Windows Server 2016 Dhcp failover configuration

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server

I've built a new AD domain and I've got 2 dhcp servers (2016 & 2019) that have been setup in a Failover partnership. I've tested it and it's working correctly. I decided to RENAME both of these servers to more meaningful names. Dhcp is still working correctly. However, when I look at the ipv4 properties under Failover, the partner servers still list the old server names. **I want this fixed.** When attempting to Deconfigure Failover(from the scope) it fails. Here's the exact message that is displayed, "Check status of the failover relationship....Failed. The dhcp service is not running on the target computer. Deconfigure failover failed. Error 1722. The dhcp Server service is not running on the target computer."
I've monkeyed around with dns cnames and other stuff to no avail. I know that i can remove the dhcp roles from both servers and add them back again to fix the problem. But, I would think that there must be another way to fix this issue. 
Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the failover relationship via PowerShell with the following command.

```
Remove-DhcpServerv4Failover -ComputerName <ServerName> -Name <DHCPFailoverRelationshipName> -Force
```

Once you run the command on both servers, you can re-create the failover relationship.

Comment: Worked like a charm...Thanks!                                                                                    
-After running the PS commands on both servers, I did have to delete the scope on the partner in order to create a new failover relationship between the 2 servers.